# Anyone run into this bug? RTMP streaming videos ending 3-4 secs too early?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, streaming, rtmp, netstream

I've created a player for a client in the past using their LimeLight server to stream videos and not had an issue before, however for a new client using different LimeLight server, the videos seem to be ending 3-4 secs too early.

My traces on 3 vastly different videos I tested:

```
metadata duration = 32        // 32 secs long, ends at 27
Stop [27.350 seconds] = 4.65 

metadata duration = 17        // 17 secs long, ends at 12
Stop [12.852 seconds] = 4.148

metadata duration = 258       // 258 secs long, ends at 255
Stop [255.861 seconds]
```

In the video players I check for `NetStream.Play.Stop` then put a 'reset' type function in there. This function however triggers too early due to this strange bug. **Has anyone have seen this before?**

---

```
private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void 
    {
        trace("connected is: " + nc.connected );

        switch (event.info.code) 
        {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                trace("Connected");
                connectStream();
                break;

            case "NetStream.Play.Start":
                trace("********** Start [" + ns.time.toFixed(3) + " seconds]");
            break;

            case "NetStream.Play.Stop":
                trace("‹ ----------- Playback has stopped. ----------- ›");
                trace("Stop [" + ns.time.toFixed(3) + " seconds]");
                if (nsBuffering){ removeChild(bufferAni); }
                nsBuffering = false;
                videoStatus = "NotPlaying";
                resetVideo(); //<- Video ends so go back to start
                // ^ This triggers too early
            break;
        }
    }
```

The only work-around I see for this is saving the initial number I get from the metadata duration, and running a timer to constantly check for when the current ns.time matches metadata and then run my reset function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### I FOUND THE FIX!

http://www.wildform.com/support/tutorials/loopingFLVs/

I had to put in a check first when the netstream hit play.stop, then call my reset function when the buffer was empty...

**The code on the site is AS2, but I converted it to AS3:**

.

```
private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void 
    {
        trace("connected is: " + nc.connected );

        switch (event.info.code) 
        {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                trace("Connected");
                connectStream();
                break;

            case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty":
                trace("‹ ----------- Buffer is Empty! ----------- ›");
                if (nsBuffering){ removeChild(bufferAni); }
                nsBuffering = false;

                if (videoFinished) // < Now I can run my reset
                {
                    resetVideo();
                    videoFinished = false;
                }

            break;

            case "NetStream.Buffer.Full":
                trace("‹ ----------- Buffer is FULL! ----------- ›");
                if (nsBuffering){ removeChild(bufferAni); }
                nsBuffering = false;
            break;

            case "NetStream.Buffer.Flush":
                trace("Data has finished streaming, remaining buffer will be emptied.");
                videoStatus = "NotPlaying";
            break;

            case "NetStream.Play.Stop":
                trace("‹ ----------- Playback has stopped. ----------- ›");

                videoFinished = true; // < This first
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is incredibly old, but I was banging my head trying to resolve this issue; and aside from your solution, there just isn't much about it online.

So, I've figured it out. If you are using rtmp, **you need to change bufferTime to false.**

Since rtmp DOES NOT cache, there is no need for buffer time, and if you set one, you are limiting yourself and eventually the buffer will be empty.

```
ns.bufferTime = false;
```

Comment: hehe thanks, and yeah I've since moved past Flash now :/ dedicated 10 years of my career to it, but should have made the jump to front end developer as soon as the iPhone was released...